# Best way to Bulk read Mongo DB - Is there anything like this?

Tags: mongodb, performance, metrics, nosql

What is the efficient way to read bulk data from MongoDB (version >=3.2). I am finding methods only for [Bulk write](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#example).

I am working on creating metrics analyzing data that is stored in mongoDB. Since I am testing waters, my tech stack is limited to Mongo Aggregation Pipeline and Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously ensuring you have the necessary indexes will ensure that the reads are efficient. As well as the native aggregation pipeline, you have mapreduce that you may be able to make use of.

Also if you are using a replica set, you may want to set your connection to read from one of your secondary nodes, instead of your primary

Answer (score 1):

You can use batch function of mongo cursor and do aggregation on that batch. Later get more to get next batch.